# How to reload the page without refresh

Tags: jquery, jsp, servlets

I want to reload some content in my web page when i call that page.

```
<jsp:include page ="/GetAllDetailsOfFollowing"  /><br>
```

I have called a servlet from a jsp page. But on the web page it is not completely executing. then i have to manually refresh the webpage then it will show all documents.
 How to solve this problem. Is there any method in jquery to reload this page immediately after reloading the web page
This is my doGet method in servlet

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Connection con = null;
        HttpSession session=request.getSession();
        String followingPerson=(String)session.getAttribute("followingPerson");
        String userName =(String)session.getAttribute("userName");
        PreparedStatement st = null;
        List dataListDetails = new ArrayList();
        List dataListTweets = new ArrayList();
        List dataListFollwers = new ArrayList();
        List dataListFollowing = new ArrayList();
        ResultSet rsForProfile = null, rsForTweets = null, rsForFollower = null, rsForFollowing = null;
        try {
            con = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
            String sql="select * from person where user_id=\""+followingPerson+"\"";
            //sql = "select * from person where user_id=\"ankur\"";
            // sql="select * from person where user_id=\""+followingPerson+"\"";
            st = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            st.executeQuery();
            rsForProfile = st.getResultSet();

            if (rsForProfile.next()) {
                dataListDetails.add("First Name");
                dataListDetails.add(rsForProfile.getString("firstName"));
                dataListDetails.add("Full Name");
                dataListDetails.add(rsForProfile.getString("fullName"));
                dataListDetails.add("User Id");
                dataListDetails.add(rsForProfile.getString("user_id"));
                dataListDetails.add("Email Id");
                dataListDetails.add(rsForProfile.getString("email_id"));
                dataListDetails.add("Joined At");
                dataListDetails.add(rsForProfile.getString("joined"));

            }
            request.setAttribute("dataListDetails", dataListDetails);
       } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                rsForProfile.close();
                rsForTweets.close();
                rsForFollower.close();
                rsForFollowing.close();
                st.close();
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException s) {

            }

        }


        RequestDispatcher rd = request
                .getRequestDispatcher("GetAllDetailOfFollowing.jsp");
        if (rd != null) {
            rd.include(request, response);
        }

    }
```

And this is my jsp which I am calling from jsp

```
<body>
<table border ="1" cellpadding="1" style="margin-left: 511px; margin-top: 56px;">

    <%
        Iterator itr;
        List data =(List)request.getAttribute("dataListDetails");
        for(itr=data.iterator();itr.hasNext();){
    %>
    <tr>
    <td width="119"><%=itr.next() %></td>
    <td width ="168"><%=itr.next() %></td>
    </tr>
    <%
        }
        request.removeAttribute("dataListDetails");
    %>
</table>
```

Basically I am including servlet in starting jsp and then that servlet including the another jsp. This last jsp will print one tale on the web page but when i will refresh the web page then it will be visible. Also tell how to remove scriplet from jsp page.

Comment: show us the code where you have called the servlet ?

Comment: I have included the servlet in JSP. Above I have written code.

Comment: so this included page (`GetAllDetailsOfFollowing`) calls the servlet  and returns something ? show us the GetAllDetailsOfFollowing page

Comment: Can someone help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this using ajax:

Firstly you have to make the ajax call when the first page loads. This can be achieved using [.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

Then use the [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) call to call your servlet like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/GetAllDetailsOfFollowing',
    data: {
        param1: 'some param',
        param2: 's0me other param'
    },
    beforeSend: function() {
        //nothing needed here
        //usually you can display a loading message
    },
    success: function(data) {
        //on success show something to the user
        //data is the html returned from the calling page, in your case the servlet
        $('#mainContainer').html(data); //put the html in the correct place
    },
    error: function() {
        //show some error message here
    }
  });
}
```

That's all I think... Enjoy

**UPDATE (Passing parameters to servlet)**

This is your JSP:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="hidden" id="param1" value="<%=someObject.getSomeAttribute()%>"/>
    <div id="mainContainer">Nothing to show yet</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then in you ajax call you can pass the `param1` to the servlet like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/GetAllDetailsOfFollowing',
  data: {
      param1: $('#param1').val()
  }..........
..............
```

And then in your servlet you can get that `param1` value using `request.getParameter("param1")`

Comment: You mean that i should make html table into servlet and do out.print().

Comment: yes, the servlet can output any html content, and using jquery you can place this output anywhere you want on the page. You can even pass parameters to servlet (see my update)

Comment: But this is wrong convention We should not use html in servlet.